# how to handle try for possible object not existing in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, try-except

I have an object that may or may not exist.  Due to this fact I have wrapped the statement in a try / except block.

```
try:
        generic_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(myentity)
        my_object = MyObject.objects.filter(content_type__pk=generic_type.id, object_id=myentity.id)[0]
except:
```

The reason I ask is because I have nothing to put in the Except condition in this situation, but django/python requires it.

Is this the proper way to handle this situation? If it is, what should I put after the Except?

Comment: `except` is what you put in for situations where the `try` block fails. In other words: what do you want the program to do when the `try` block would otherwise throw an error?

Comment: I want it to move down into my program and execute other unrelated code

Comment: Then user Wooble's comment about `pass` is what to include in there. It's worth saying, though, that your construction up there can hide all kinds of errors once you put a `pass` in there, in part because you're not specifying the error you think will crop up. You're catching all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pass` statement anywhere a statement is required when you want to do nothing, although you should specify the actual exception to catch.

```
except WhateverExceptionGetsRaised:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving an object based on "PK" then it is only going to return one object.  There isn't a need for multiple filters.  Instead of:

```
my_object = MyObject.objects.filter(content_type__pk=generic_type.id, object_id=myentity.id)[0]
```

You can use:

```
my_object = MyObject.objects.get(content_type__pk=generic_type.id, '')
```

You would use this if you want it to return nothing hence the double single quotes if it fails to get the first object specified.  This may be a more concise answer than an try/except pattern.  Also, using:

```
filter()[0] vs. get()
```

will both return one object, but `filter()[0]` returns a `QuerySet` object type, where as `get()` returns the object only, so this is another thing to consider.